# Redirect apache from http to https on amazon Linux AMI

Tags: wordpress, apache, https

I've struggled with this for a couple of hours now and I just feel it shouldn't be this hard.

I've got 3 domains that I want to redirect to https://www.shimara.com

I'm only hosting one website on the server so I don't mind a heavy handed approach here if it works. In my httpd.conf I've got:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
        ServerName "shimara.com"
        ServerAlias "www.shimara.com"
        ServerAlias "shimara.co.uk"
        ServerAlias "www.shimara.co.uk"
        ServerAlias "shimara.com.au"
        ServerAlias "www.shimara.com.au"
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?shimara\.co.uk$ [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?shimara\.com$ [NC]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?shimara\.com.au$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^ https://www.shimara.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R] 
</VirtualHost>
```

.co.uk and .com.au redirect to https correctly but drops the www.
The .com address does not redirect to a secure site. I've got a blank .htaccess in the web root

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: The currently functioning redirects are not result of this configuration.

Comment: Any ideas where they could be coming from?

Comment: Is there another `VirtualHost` above this one in `httpd.conf`? Perhaps you are looking at the wrong `httpd.conf`? Can you put `RewriteRule ^ - [F]` directly under `RewriteEngine on` and see what happens?